# I WILL ASK ABOUT DOWNLOADING A NEW PROGRAM IN MY WINDOWS PHONE

Tags: lumia

I am an adult and i have an NOKIA Lumia and when i want to download a game or a program by the Net a message come to me when say that you should have your configuration of your family. I have an account in windows but i cant buy anything in the Net. This is a big problem for me . I hope you will consider my message. I am waiting for your solution.